# De Morgans laws - which law is this and how is it used?

Tags: probability, statistics

Wondering how my lecturer made this step, as i can't quite figure out which law of De Morgan's that was used and how.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JpiQ.png
Tyvm for your help.

Comment: Used both $(A \cup B)^c=(A^c \cap B^c)$ and $(A \cap B)^c=(A^c \cup B^c)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The steps are: $(\cap \cup A_m)^c=\cup(\cup A_m)^c=(\cup \cap A_m^c)$